# i have question about java function signature

Tags: java, lambda

I found that function interface and getMethod seem to be replaceable, What makes it work?

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> collect = Stream.of(new App(), new App(), new App())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(App::getString, (app) -> "aaa"));

    }

    public String getString() {
        return "str";
    }
}
```

But when I use lambda to replace getMethod, it fails . Why this does not work

```
        Map<String, String> collect = Stream.of(new App(), new App(), new App())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(() -> "str", (app) -> "aaa"));
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of failure you are getting? Compilation error? Runtime exception? Which one? It's kind of annoying having to copy your code into a Java development environment just to reconstruct useful information readily available to you ...

Comment: is compilation error.

Comment: Which compilation error? Why are you handicapping people who want to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collectors.toMap` requires a `Function<? super T, ? extends K>` as its first parameter, where `T` is the type of elements in the stream, and `K` is the key type of the map you want.

In this case, you have a stream of `App`s and you want a `Map<String, String>`, so `T` is `App` and `K` is `String`. In other words, you need a function that accepts an `App`, and returns a `String`.

`App::getString` is such a `Function<? super T, ? extends K>`. You might be wondering why it accepts a `App` when `getString` accepts no parameters. Notice how `getString` is an instance method, and you are referring to it without an instance! A method reference of the form `ClassName::instanceMethodName` implicitly accepts an extra parameter of type `ClassName`, because you need an instance of that class to call it!

On the other hand, your lambda is not such a function. It accepts no parameters, as indicated by the empty brackets at the start (`()`). Your lambda expression would be represented by the `Supplier<String>` functional interface, not the `Function<App, String>` that you need.

To use a lambda expression here, simply do what you did to the second parameter of `toMap`, and add a lambda parameter:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap((app) -> "str", (app) -> "aaa"));
//                         ^^^
```

Note that this is required even if you don't use `app` in the lambda expression.